Putting total population survival probability as well as sub populations on the same plot
I can make good looking KM survival curves using ggsurvplot - but what I want to do is have a plot with total population as well as the two patient subgroups so the viewer can see the tot pop as a reference when looking at the subpopulations. I have searched but cant seem to find anything to get me what I want.  Is there a simple or non-simple way to do what I want?
I tried changing the fit to basically include the null model but that didn't work.

HI Buttercup, you will likely get better, faster help if you edit your question to include sample data and reproducible code, including what you have tried and why it hasn't worked. Good luck!

One way is rbind the dataset to itself, creating a third subgroup.
library(survival)
library(survminer)

lung2 <- mutate(lung, sex=3) |>
  rbind(lung)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung2)

ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung2, 
           legend="top", legend.title="",
           legend.labs=c("Sex=1", "Sex=2", "Overall"))



